How can a string parameter be of type byte * and of type wchar_t * at the same time?
I am currently looking into the WinHttp API and have come across the WinHttpConnect() function which is described here. The parameter description is quite worrying for me. The aforementioned page first gives the function prototype as
WINHTTPAPI HINTERNET WinHttpConnect(
  [in] HINTERNET     hSession,
  [in] LPCWSTR       pswzServerName,
  [in] INTERNET_PORT nServerPort,
  [in] DWORD         dwReserved
);

and continues with the parameter description. The second input parameter is explained as follows (leaving away the last two irrelevant sentences):

[in] pswzServerName
Pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the host name of an HTTP server. Alternately, the string can contain the IP address of the site in ASCII, for example, 10.0.1.45. [...]

That's the part I am struggling with. In C, a string consists either of wide characters (as the parameter type LPCWSTR implies) or of bytes (as the wording "IP address [...] in ASCII" implies). It is not clear to me how the function can distinguish whether the bytes at the memory location the parameter points to are bytes making up a narrow string or are wide characters making up a wide string.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

It's a typo. It should read "... the IP address of the site as a string." I will fix the documentation.

Thanks a lot for the fast answer! To be sure: That means if I have an IP address as an array of unsigned char, I convert it to an array of wchar_t (e.g. using mbstowcs()), and then use the converted wchar_t array as parameter?

@Binarus - usual LPCWSTR , like L"10.0.1.45"

@Binarus no, you do not convert the IP's raw bytes as-is to wide characters. The function wants the string representation of the IP address. Also, "ASCII" does not imply a byte* string. A wchar_t* Unicode string can have ASCII characters. They are just plain characters whose values are below 128.

Thanks for the comments, and +1. But I haven't got it yet: I have the IP address in an unsigned char array (that's because I am in a DLL that exports functions to another application, and I obtain the IP address from the other application, and the other application provides and needs strings encoded as byte arrays with one byte per character). On the other hand, WinHttpConnect() expects the second parameter to be a string that consists of wchar_t characters; that is, there are always two bytes per character, even for ASCII characters. Therefore I do need that conversion, don't I?

look for RtlIpv4AddressToStringW for convert address to string and RtlIpv6AddressToStringW for ipv6 address. can use Ex version, if need with port. can use RtlIpv4StringToAddress[Ex]W for convert back string to address

also you can use WSAAddressToString for more generic conversion ( any sockaddr )

@RbMm Thank for the tips! However, the functions you have mentioned convert numerical values to strings and vice versa, while I need to convert a string that is encoded with 1 byte per character to a string that is encoded with 2 bytes per character. The former is what the DLL functions obtains from (and must return to) their callers, the latter is what the WinHttp functions use.

Unclear what format your input is in. Is it unsigned char addr[] = { 10, 0, 1, 45 }; or is it unsigned char addr[] = { '1', '0', '.', '0', '.', '1', '.', '4', '5', '\0' }?

@Binarus in what problem convert ansi to unicode and back ? MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte

@RaymondChen The input format is unsigned char addr[] = { '1', '0', '.', '0', '.', '1', '.', '4', '5', '\0' }. The problem was that I was unable to understand if I could pass this addr directly to WinHttpConnect() or whether I had to convert it to a wchar_t string first. If I understand your first comment correctly, the latter is the case.

@RbMm No problem with the conversion itself; MultiByteToWideChar() would be the way to go. However, the problem was that I was unable to understand from the WinHttpConnect() function description whether I needed that conversion or not.

Yes, you need to convert the string from unsigned char[] to wchar_t[].

@RaymondChen Thank you very much again! I'll take that route and test it next week.

Unrelated: Why do you want to use WinHttp ?

@MichaelChourdakis After researching the options it seemed to me that WinHttp was the current recommended Win32 API for such tasks. I may be wrong, though; in this case, I'd surely be grateful for other suggestions. In every case, the API would have to come with all bells and whistles: SSL / TLS with options to ignore certificate errors, determine TLS versions, ability to set headers, ability to POST, GET, PUT and so on, and ability to set every option, e.g. timeout. I found WinHttp hard to understand, but to be quite complete.

@Binarus is it about creating a server? If you only need a client, then WinInet is easier.

@MichaelChourdakis It's about creating a client. We have an industrial control for a machine tool. The control needs to communicate with IO-Link masters via REST API. The control can be programmed using a variant of Basic. The control provides commands to send characters via TCP/IP, but does not provide an HTTP(s) client. But it can use Windows DLLs to extend its abilities. And here we go :-) Regarding WinInet: I have noticed WinInet during my initial research, but something was against it. I can't remember exactly (it's six months ago); eventually it was the lacking session isolation.

ASCII can refer to two things.
It can refer to the ASCII encoding, in which case it does imply bytes  and thus char *.
But it can also refer to the ASCII character set, meaning the symbols that can be encoded using ASCII.
The second is closer to what is meant here. "the IP address of the site in ASCII" means "the text representation of the IP address of the site". In other words, you are to expected to provide the text form (e.g. L"10.0.1.45") of the address rather than its packed form ("\x0A\x00\x01\x2D") or its numerical form (0x0A00012D).

OK, great, accepted and +1. Thank you very much for rewording the sentence in question and for making its meaning clear that way.
